# How do i recover corrupted tar.gz archives in Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, archive, gzip

So i have an data archive in the Tar.gz format and it got corrupted,in a weird way.
So it has it's original file size that it had before it got corrupted which was something around 2.0GB,but only displayed 700Mb before the archive manager either stops or displays an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 'official' stance about data recovery from a damaged gz file: http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt

[Gzrecover](https://github.com/arenn/gzrt) (gZip Recovery Toolkit) is designed to attempt data recovery. Results vary. Also please notice the warning:

*ATTENTION!!!!  99% of "corrupted" gzip archives are caused by transferring
the file via FTP in ASCII mode instead of binary mode.  Please re-transfer
the file in the correct mode first before attempting to recover from a file
you believe is corrupted.*